# Передача значения переменной из модуля в основную программу (Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Работаю с Raspberry Pi. Написал программу для вывода списка файлов на текстовый экран и листания его тактовыми кнопками. Подключил свою программу к программе Pronterface. 
Pronterface запускается, в процессе работы вызывает мою программу, моя программ записывает имя выбранного файла в переменную, Pronterface получает эту переменную и работает с ней. В пробном варианте значение этой переменной записывается в файл txt.

Кусок кода моей программы(program.py)

```
...............
if GPIO.input(16) == False:
          tex=images[i]
          tex=str(tex)
          GPIO.cleanup()
          exit()
...........
```

Кусок кода Pronterface:

```
import program
......
program.main()
....
def getText():
        return program.tex
....
zz=getText()
my=open("File.txt", "w")
my.write(zz)
my.close()
```

После нажатия на кнопку, висящей на GPIO16 все закрывается. А если убрать exit(), то ничего не происходит - агрузка Pronterface стоит на том же месте, на каком была вызвана моя программа

На всякий случай ниже выкладываю полный код моей программы и Pronterface.
http://rghost.ru/64bHTWYxj

Comment: Тут важен контекст модуля. tex глобальна? тот код, в котором вы присваете tex, нужно бы добавить `globals tex`. Да и так важно хранить именно переменную? Может лучше замутить функцию, которая и будет возвращать значение и дергать функцию?

Comment: Кстати, код не выкладывайте в файлообменники, особенно, если файлов немного. Тот же pastebin больше подойдет. И вы пишите, что программа ваша, но судя по лицензиям исходников нет. Для таких случаях, я добавляю после копирайта автора свой (для (L)GPL), но не удаляю его

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Создаете глобальную переменную `tex`, выше `tex=images[i]`, до присваивания `tex`, пишите `global text`. Без `globals` в области видимости `if` будет создана новая ссылка `tex`, которая уничтожится сразу после выхода из `if`.

**Немного примеров:**

Вот тут не надо использовать `global`, т.к. `text` в пределах области модуля:

```
text = "DFDF"
print(text)

if True:
    text = "AAA"
    print(text)

print(text)
```

Однако, если захотим использовать в функции модуля глобальную переменную `text`:

```
text = "DFDF"
print(text)  # DFDF

def f():
    if True:
        text = "AAA"
        print(text)  # AAA

f()

print(text)  # DFDF
```

Чтобы изменения произошли, нужно добавить `global`:

```
text = "DFDF"
print(text)  # DFDF


def f():
    if True:
        global text
        text = "AAA"
        print(text)  # AAA

f()

print(text)  # AAA
```